# TYPO3 on MAMP can't log into install tool

Tags: typo3, mamp, typo3-6.2.x, mamp-pro, typo3-4.5

After having set up a TYPO3 4.5.40 site (for upgrading to 6.2) locally with MAMP PRO 3.2.1 on OS X, everything works fine - except the login into the install tool.

There is no feedback about a wrong password, only an error 500 after the timeout.

When set to CGI mode, the apaches error log says:

```
[Tue May 19 18:00:40 2015] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.3.29.fcgi", referer: http://site.dev/typo3/install/index.php
```

Running PHP as a module, it still talks about fastCGI, strange:

```
FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 11681)
```

It doesn't help either.

Changing the PHP version or disabling OPCache doesn't help either (OPCache has been disabled by CodeKit before).

I've had that before (with 6.2!), and solved it by setting the site up in a new directory. But if that happens all the time, I need to know the cause.

Where could I look?
What makes the install tool login different to the BE login, which works fine?
Could it be some setting in MAMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha!

There must be something wrong with the postfix setup in MAMP 3.2.1 or my Settings.

I checked the postfix log and it says:

```
May 19 20:50:51 myname.local postfix/postdrop[18672]: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/744151.18672: Permission denied
```

I don't know how to fix that, but if `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['warning_email_addr']` is disabled, the install tool login works again.

So the install tool was trying to send that email all the time and wouldn't give up.